# How get foursquare friends feed by API

Tags: api, feed, foursquare

How get foursquare friends feed by API? When I'm using **checkins/recent**, API back recent checkins only last chekin per user.

Example: some user checkins in two locations with 5 minute time interval. When I'm using **checkins/recent**, I see only second checking i.e. last checkin.

Answer (score 0):

This case isn't currently supported by the Foursquare API. You can only get a full check-in history ("feed") for users that you have OAuth tokens for.

Comment: How another developers used foursquare feed in apps?